# How do I know when I'm done crawling a domain?

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize

I've written a function in Python that gets all the links on a page. 
Then, I run that function for all of the links that first function returned.

My question is, if I were to keep on doing this using CNN as my starting point, how would I know when I had crawled all (or most) of CNN's webpages?

Here's the code for the crawler.

```
base_url = "http://www.cnn.com"
title = "cnn"
my_file = open(title+".txt","w")

def crawl(site): 
    seed_url = site
    br = Browser()

    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_equiv(False)

    br.open(seed_url)

    link_bank = []

    for link in br.links():
        if link.url[0:4] == "http":
            link_bank.append(link.url)
        if link.url[0] == "/":
            url = link.url
            if url.find(".com") == -1:
                if url.find(".org") == -1: 
                    link_bank.append(base_url+link.url)
                else:
                    link_bank.append(link.url)
            else:
                link_bank.append(link.url)

        if link.url[0] == "#":
            link_bank.append(base_url+link.url)

    link_bank = list(set(link_bank))

    for link in link_bank:
        my_file.write(link+"\n")

    return link_bank

my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not specifically look into your code, but you should look up how to implement a breadth-first-search, and additionally store already visited URLs in a `set`. If you find a new URL in the currently visited page, append it to the list of URLs to visit, if it wasn't in the `set` already.

You might need to ignore the query string (everything after the question mark in a URL).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing coming into my mind is to have a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of `visited` links. Each time you are requesting a link, add a link to a set. Before requesting a link, check if it is not in the set.

Another point is that you are actually reinventing the wheel here, [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework has [link extracting mechanism](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) built-in - it's worth using.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I took a look at scrapy, but it's incredibly arduous to install. But the set() idea will work, I think.

Comment: @kttr have you looked into Scrapy, has it helped?

Comment: This was a blast from the past, haha. I just used Google's custom search engine API to search specific websites because its results were far better than anything I could have done myself. As for Scrapy, it looks much more accessible and useful now that I've had almost 2 years more of programming experience :P. (But I haven't needed to use it since).

Comment: @kttr yeah, going through the old answers and cleaning up :)